# How can I rearrange items within Organizations and Courses on my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

On LinkedIn I used the [profile sections](http://blog.linkedin.com/2011/07/15/student-profile-sections/) feature to add some courses I've taken and organizations I participate in.

[image]

The Organizations have dates associated with them but this does not seem to affect the order in which they appear. The Courses don't even have dates. How can I effectively rearrange courses and organizations once I've added them?

Answer (score 2):

In LinkedIn, first click on the *Edit Profile* menu option. Now, scroll to the section where you wish to re-arrange the order of item appearance.

There is a grey bar that appears to the left of each entry when you hover. Click and drag to the sequence that is appropriate.

Comment: Since the update, they added auto-sorting by school, but there is no longer a gray bar when you hover to assist with sorting, so manual reordering is not currently an option. :(